# How can I load JSON data and use it as dataProvider for dataGroup?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Im experimenting with how to create custom item renderers in flex 4.6 and have a data source that is in JSON format... Im using the following to retrieve the json data and it works and I can access the data fine

```
myJSONdata[i].id
myJSONdata[i].username   etc...
```

but am having a problem understanding how to go about making this data the data type that flex expects  (ArrayList, ArrayCollection?) for the dataProvider assigned to a dataGroup.

```
public var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
public var jsonContent:URLLoader;
public var myJSONdata:Object;
public var request:URLRequest;

public function Init():void {

request = new URLRequest("URL TO THE JSON DATA...");
loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, jsonLoaded);
}


public function jsonLoaded(event:Event):void {

jsonContent = URLLoader(event.target);      
myJSONdata = JSON.parse(jsonContent.data);  

trace(myJSONdata.length);               

}
```

When I try to assign the dataProvider like this...

```
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="myJSONdata">
```

I get this error:

```
Initializer for 'dataProvider': values of type mx.collections.IList cannot be represented in text.
```

I'd like to use the same data access functionality and then have that data serve as an array that I can then use as a dataProvider for the dataGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Either give your DataGroup and id and assign the dataProvider in AS3 like this :

```
<s:DataGroup id="myDataGroup">

//in as3

myDataGroup.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myJSONdata);
```

Or you can assign it like you do in MXML but would have to wrap the variable name in curly braces.

```
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{myJSONdata}">
```

The reason why you are getting that error is because MXML is treating `myJSONdata` as a normal string.

You might still need to put the JSON array in an ArrayCollection like I did with the first example.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help... when I try

   myDataGroup.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myJSONdata);

I get this error message...

    Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Array.

Comment: If your myJSONdada is an array you can do `myDataGroup.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myJSONdata as Array);` If it is not an array you will need to loop through it and add it's elements to an array before creating an `ArrayCollection`

Comment: PERFECT... finally can see the data... now i get to continue trying to learn how to do custom itemrenderers...  thanks for your help @Ban

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is old but this could still be useful, maybe to someone else.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:HTTPService id="jsonLoader" result="jsonLoader_resultHandler(event)"
                   url="http://example.com/sample.json" />
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.adobe.serializers.json.JSONDecoder;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        //<s:WindowedApplication .... creationComplete="initApp()">
        public function initApp():void
        {
            //so trigger jsonLoader to load the json data from the link
            // using the HTTPService immediately the application starts;
            jsonLoader.send();
        }

        protected function jsonLoader_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var jsonContent:Object = (new JSONDecoder()).decode(event.result.toString());
            //Assuming jsonContent.data is an Array
            resultDataGrid.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(jsonContent.data);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```